# How to animate a CSS animation when it comes to view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I created a progress bar animation,i had place that at bottom of my site.but it animates so after site loads and before it comes to view.
How can i animate the progress bar when it comes to view?

component.

```
class Skill extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
        <div>
            <div data-aos='fade-right' className="front">
                <div className="skills">
                    <h1>Front-End</h1>
                        <li>
                            <h3>HTML</h3><span className="bar"><span className="html"></span></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>CSS</h3><span className="bar"><span className="css"></span></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>JavaScript</h3><span className="bar"><span className="javascript"></span></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <h3>React</h3><span className="bar"><span className="react"></span></span>
                        </li>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className="back">
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    };

}
```

Full code available in [codepen](https://codepen.io/chawki726/pen/zeoJQY?editors=0010)

Comment: https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/exporting-pens/

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `node-sass` by running `npm install node-sass --save` or `yarn add node-sass`
2. Download your dependencies in 2 separate files and load them in `public/index.html`
3. Rename your files `.css` to `.scss`
4. And it is done now. You can use `SCSS` in your React app.

Also, you can review the [Official SCSS Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet)

Comment: will it work if i link those two in my public/index.html file like ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.15/minified/require.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/ironwallaby/delaunay/master/delaunay.js">```

Comment: no to use .js files use <script> tag like this

`<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.15/minified/require.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks,and i know this is little mess problem and here is my codepen https://codepen.io/chawki726/pen/XOWGgR and now where to paste those code in react component?please help me friend